# Database joins / FK - basic questions

Tags: database

There are 2 tables A & B. Each has say 10 colums.
Table A has 8 columns as FK to other tables. Table B uses enums and std colunms without any FK.

- So which table is faster / better to
  use?
- If i do any action with table A,
  i assume I only have to touch colunms
  I am relating the action too and do
  not have to join all the 10 FK tables
  even if i only need 1 FK colunm?
- If i do
  need to perform any action on a FK,
  like write, update or delete a value,
  do i need to join to the parent
  table?
- If i understand correctly,
  EAV model is better than a expanded
  colunm table because if i need to
  display two text from the table then
  i need to use a inner join for the
  colunm table for for a EAV table i
  can use a regular select only with no join?

Answer (score 0):

1. For only a few values and if the amount of values doesn't change, ENUM can be faster and takes up less space. However, to later add possible values, you'll need to alter the entire table, which is not good design. Table A is in most cases the better option.
2. Offcourse you only join the table A with the tables you need.
3. No, you can just modify the table containing the value, unless you change the PK. You should however design your tables in such way that changing the PK is not often needed - use artificial PK's (autoincrements are perfect). Even countries cease to exist or change names...
4. No, for your EAV you'll need the join. However, joining on keys is extremely fast... this is what relational databases are all about, it's their strong point.

Comment: To point 4 but i will still need a join with the colunm table too? I am seeking a table like Categories and subcategories which has colunms like id, category_id, parent_id. So I have to always join to get multiple subcategories of a parent right?